# how to stop fetching?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I have 2 buttons in my `View`. `fetch` and `stop` buttons. And when i press `fetch` button my method get data and put it to `textView`'s text. But if i press `stop` button i want to stop fetching. I know that i can't stop request but when i press `stop` button it mustn't change `textView`'s text. To be more clear when it finished fetching data, my program mustn't get back.
 Here's my `fetch` method:

```
- (void) pressedFetch
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self fetchJson]];
    });
}
```

i want to do it by like `callBack` method. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was wrong way. And i changed my method. I did it with `NSURLSession`. it has method that is named `invalidateAndCancel`. if i use this method my `session` is canceled and `fetching` is stoped.

```
- (void) pressedFetch
{
  NSString *jsonUrl = @"http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=6600&country=AT&username=demo";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *conf = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
    session = [NSURLSession
               sessionWithConfiguration:conf
               delegate:self
               delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    task = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request]; //NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = ...
    [task resume];
}

- (void) pressedStop
{
  [session invalidateAndCancel]; //NSURLSession *session = ...
}
```

it was so easy )))

Comment: of course, then you can get data by using `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate`'s methods

Answer (score 2):

Don't use GCD, use the higher level `NSOperation` API which offers cancellation support. In your operation subclass you can then check for the operation being cancelled before using the downloaded data. To cancel you use the operation queue `cancelAllOperations` method.

Your operation can be an instance of `NSBlockOperation`, and assuming that `fetchJson` is synchronous, something like:

```
NSOperation *op = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    id json = [self fetchJson];

    if (![self isCancelled]) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", json];
        });
    }
}];
```

Comment: can u explain clearly? in my `pressedStop` method i want to cancel this `operation` to coming back. don't want to check changing textView

Comment: @Wain is right. `NSOperationQueue` is the right way. Create an `NSOperationQueue` property, synthesize it. When beginning operation, instead of starting it, you only add it the `operationQueue` : `[myOperationQueue addOperation:myOperation];`.It depends on your request, whether it's a block operation, or a request operation. In the cancelButton target method, cancel the request using: `[myOperationQueue cancelAllOperations];`

Answer (score 1):

If you just don't want to show the fetched data on tapping Stop button,

```
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender
{
     textView.text = @""
}
```

or if you are using NSURLConnection to fetch the data from server, you can call Cancel on it

```
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender
{
    [urlConnection cancel];  // NSURLConnection *connection;
    /* After this method is called, the connection’s delegate no longer receives any messages for the connection. If you want to reattempt the connection, you should create a new connection object.*/
}
```

Comment: my goal is canceling `fetching operation`, not to change `TextView`'s text to empty. i can't cancel connection

Comment: then you can go with NSURLConnection and call cancel on it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to check you data already download in your class or not.
if not than you can download data and store in a file through archive in document directory next time check it is available in document directory and the unarchived your data and use it.